# LOTS of call to the expire method of the SQLAlchemy's InstanceState class

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, innodb

I'm performing data crunching tasks with 11 parallel processes and the results of each computation is logged in an InnoDB table of a MySQL database, using the ORM of SQLAlchemy. However, processing times are larger than expected. If I profile the execution of one of these parallel process, I can see that about 30% of the time is spent in the expire method of the InstanceState class, which gets called... 292,957,736 times!

The computation is performs a loop with 17,106 iterations, and one commit is performed for each iteration. In the profile, I see that the commit method is called 17,868 which seem to be in the good order of magnitude (the 761 supplementary commit probably being from other parts of the surrounding code). However, it is not that clear to me what that expire method does and why it should be called that many time. Is it called on EVERY rows of the table at every commit or what? It looks a bit like that since if 17,106^2 == 292,615,236... Is this behavior normal? Are there any recipes or advices on how to do thing better in this kind of situation? The exact code is a bit complicated [it is in the [__computeForEvent(...) method of this file](https://bitbucket.org/christian_oreilly/spyndle/src/master/spyndle/propagation/XCST.py)]  but, the SQLAlchemy part is conceptually equivalent to this:

```
for i in range(17106):
    propagations = []
    for i in range(19):
        propagations.append(Propagation(...))
    session.add_all(propagations)
    session.commit()
```

where Propagation is a Base subclass.
Any advice on how to speed things and avoid this explosion of expire(...) calls would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

292M calls to expire() would indicate that there are this many objects present in memory when commit() is called, which is an unbelievably huge number in fact.

One immediate way to nix these expire calls is just to turn [expire_on_commit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#committing) to False:

```
sess = Session(expire_on_commit=False)
```

a more subtle way to get around this, but that would require a little more care, is to just not hold onto all those objects in memory, if we did:

```
for i in range(17106):
    session.add_all([Propagation() for i in range(19)])
    session.commit()
```

if that list of Propagation() objects were not strongly referenced without reference cycles, assuming cPython they would be garbage collected at the point of de-reference, and would not be subject to the expiration call within commit().

Still another strategy might be just to delay the commit() until after the loop, instead using flush() to process each set of items at a time.  that way most objects will have been garbage collected by the time the commit() is reached.

expire_on_commit remains the most direct way to solve this, though.

Comment: I've not tested all of your suggestions but I've ended up refactoring the code, using only flushes in the main code. I moved the commit/rollback logic outside, at the "caller" level. This change provided a better control on the state of the database (i.e. avoid inconsistent states in regards of my particular application) and fixed my expiration problem.